# Как нарисовать строку из файла в win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, c

Доброго времени суток! Вопрос - есть код проекта win32, рисующий простейшие фигуры, код рабочий. Нужно, чтобы в этом коде рисовалась не заданная фигура, а взятая из файла. Из файла считывается строка с описанием фигуры типа: "Ellipse(hdc,100,15,rt.right-100,rt.bottom-15)" как сделать, чтобы программа ее распознала, прочитала и исполнила. Далее привожу рабочий рисующий код, в котором на данный момент рисуется фигура, заданная в самом коде, а из файла берется текст:

```
case WM_PAINT:
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
// TODO: Add any drawing code here...
RECT rt;
GetClientRect(hWnd,&rt);
pen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID,3,RGB(70,10,90));
oldpen=(HPEN)SelectObject(hdc,pen);
Ellipse(hdc,100,15,rt.right-100,rt.bottom-15); // рисует эллипс
_fgetts(text,20,fa);//где TCHAR text[60]=_T("hgjhgj"); 
SelectObject(hdc,oldpen);
DrawText(hdc,text,1,&rt,DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE); // пишет текстовую строку, считанную из файла fa
DeleteObject(pen);
InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,FALSE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - это выбрать определенный легко воспринимаемый формат файла, читать его по строкам, парсить, и отрисовывать.  То есть, например, что-то вроде

```
Команда - параметр, ...
Команда - параметр, ...
...
```

Читаем строку за строкой, в зависимости от значения команды в переключателе вызываем разный код отрисовки.

Если формат изменять нельзя (это реальный исходник), то дело сильно усложняется. Желательно его подключить к своему исходнику и собрать вместе с ним.

**Дополнение**.

Рисуете так:

```
switch (command) {
    case ELLIPSE:
        DrawEllipse(...)
    break;
    ...
}
```

Значения command и параметров отрисовки берете из файла для каждой строки. Функции рисования - на MSDN для GDI+.

Comment: спасибо!
да, у меня был один из вариантов парсить(но для этого видимо структуру надо будет отдельную создавать и привязывать)
главный вопрос-как ее потом заставить рисовать эту строку?для текста есть функция рисования DrawText-впихнул внутрь текст она рисует. а для фигур пишется просто название фигуры(параметры). если я все это считаю из файла, какой функцией можно дать коанду рисовать?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: error C3861: 'DrawEllipse': identifier not found
 error C3861: 'DrawRectangle': identifier not found

не видит он функции,больше ни на что не ругается...
хотя на MSDN не написано что надо какие то библиотеки подключать дополнительно!

Comment: Имелась в виду функция Ellipse. Соответственно не DrawRectangle а просто Rectangle.

Comment: да)))спасибо!!отлаживаю)))